# Custom Python logging method

Tags: python, django, logstash

I'd like to use `python-logstash` in my Django application and need to pass 'extra' fields. [Here are the docs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-logstash).

```
extra = {"app":"app-live","source":"django_log"}
```

I would prefer not to go through and change all of my logger calls, for example:

`logger.info('Information blah.')` to `logger.info('Information blah.', extra=extra)`

The `extra` will be the same for every single call and is required. I would prefer to override the existing logger methods so that I can just do this once.

Is there a way to do this in the logging handlers in the Django `settings.py` or how and where can I override the logger methods to always add the `extra` args?

Comment: With a normal function you can freeze a portion of a call using `functools.partial` but if logger is a class then this doesn't work for methods.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do that globally with a [Filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#filter-objects) as described in the [logging cookbook](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#using-filters-to-impart-contextual-information).

To simplify things a bit, Django provides a [CallbackFilter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/logging/#django.utils.log.CallbackFilter).
Your filter function would look like this:

```
def logstash_filter(record):
    record.app = 'app-live'
    record.source = 'django_log'
    return True
```

And your logging config something like this.

```
...
'filters': {
    'add_logstash_info': {
        '()': 'django.utils.log.CallbackFilter',
        'callback': logstash_filter,
    }
},
'handlers': {
    'logstash': {
        ...
        'filters': ['add_logstash_info'],
    },
...
```

Comment: Thanks @daniel, the `extra` data isn't showing up in logstash. Do I need to return the record from the filter?

Comment: @greenafrican the example was a bit generic, in your case the filter should be applied to the logstash handler. Also note that the return statement was missing in my filter method